# Excel Pivot Filter PivotItems Listing at times as Hidden or Not Visible in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, pivotitem

My basic requirement i am trying to solve is that i want to be able to store all the selections IN THE FILTER OF a pivot table and save them, letting the user reapply them as "stored filters".  All of the code (including a hidden worksheet with the filters pivot field / value is part of an excel macro (XLAM) file.  That XLAM has a macro that:

- Runs through each pivot field in the pivot table that is a page or row field
- If it has any NOT visible items (ie if it is being used as a filter), i will store the visible items in the hidden workbook with pivot field name / pivot item name pairs

Then i will be able to reapply the filter.

HOWEVER, at some times when you access the filter and go through pivotitems in a field ALL of the pivot items are showing with .visible = false, even though the pivot is clearly filtered and does show values.

For example, with the Product Type pivot field, here were the currently selected values

Product Type values

[image: 1]

Debugging a bit shows that when i go through this "Project Type" field i get (this is a sample debug function to easily show the problem i'm having):

```
Public Sub ProjectTypePivotTest()
Dim pf As PivotField, pi As PivotItem

    Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Project Type")
    For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
        Debug.Print "'" & pi.Name & "' Visible:  " & pi.Visible
    Next pi
   
   
End Sub
```

This gives the following output (ALL FALSE even though most should be TRUE):

```txt
'Business' Visible: False
'Business Support Project (BSR ‘s)' Visible: False
'Core Support Project' Visible: False
'XYZ agile' Visible: False
'XYZ Scrum' Visible: False
'XYZ XP' Visible: False
'Discovery' Visible: False
'EDF' Visible: False
'Out of Office' Visible: False
'Production Support Project' Visible: False
```

If i then MANUALLY change the second pivot item in the list to be UNCHECKED (the BSR line) and rerun that same macro I get the correct results...

```txt
'Business' Visible: False
'Business Support Project (BSR ‘s)' Visible: False
'Core Support Project' Visible: True
'XYZ agile' Visible: True
'XYZ Scrum' Visible: True
'XYZ XP' Visible: True
'Discovery' Visible: True
'EDF' Visible: True
'Out of Office' Visible: False
'Production Support Project' Visible: True
```

Can anyone theorize why I am getting the wrong values at times instead of what is actually selected?

Additional background if it helps debug...

- The code is in an XLAM file, not the workbook with the pivot table
- The workbook with the pivot table does NOT have the baseline data in it any more, it is generated from a HUGE set of baseline data and published with the pivot tables